# C++ Program for rail fence cipher

Tags: c++

When I run the below program I got garbage value in str1 and str2.So

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,len,j=0,k=0;
    char plain[15],cip[15],str1[10],str2[10];
    cout<<"Enter Plain Text:";
    cin>>plain;
    cout<<endl;
    len=strlen(plain);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            str1[j]=plain[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
            {
                str2[k]=plain[i];
                k++;
            }
        }
    j=0;

    cout<<"Str1:"<<str1<<endl<<"Str2:"<<str2;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is "rail fance"?

Comment: Looks like you are implementing a [Rail Fence Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher)?

Comment: You forgot `str1[j] = '\0'; str2[k] = '\0';` after the loop, so the output continues after useful content until it occasionally hits a zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `str1` and `str2` are not null terminated. Change the variable definitions to `str1[10]={},str2[10]={}` [example](http://ideone.com/eCjpbU).

Comment: You are right i observed that after terminating it,Its work perfectly.Thanxx

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
void encode(int num_rails,char plain_text[],char cipher_text[])
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i=1;i<=num_rails;i++)
    {
        if(i==1||i==num_rails)
        {
            for(j=i-1;j<strlen(plain_text);j+=2*(num_rails-1))
            {
                cipher_text[k++]=plain_text[j];             
            }                           
        }
        else
        {
            cipher_text[k++]=plain_text[i-1];
            for(j=i-1;j<strlen(plain_text);)
            {
                int x=0;
                x++;
                if(x%2==1)
                {
                    j=j+2*(num_rails-i);
                }
                else
                {
                    j=j+2*(i-1);                        
                }
                cipher_text[k++]=plain_text[j];
            }       
        }
    }
    cipher_text[10]='\0';
}
void decode(int num_rails,char cipher_text[],char decrypt_text[],int length)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int y=strlen(cipher_text);
    //printf("%d\n",y);
    for(i=1;i<=num_rails;i++)
    {
        if(i==1||i==num_rails)
        {

            for(j=i-1;j<length;j+=2*(num_rails-1))
            {
                decrypt_text[j]=cipher_text[k++];   
                //printf("%d\n",j);         
            }
        }                           
        else
        {   
            decrypt_text[i-1]=cipher_text[k++];
            for(j=i-1;j<length;)
            {
                int x=0;
                x++;
                if(x%2==1)
                {
                    j=j+2*(num_rails-i);
                }
                else
                {
                    j=j+2*(i-1);                        
                }
                decrypt_text[j]=cipher_text[k++];
            }   
        }
    }   
}
int main()
{
    char plain_text[100],cipher_text[100],decrypt_text[100];
    printf("ENTER PLAIN TEXT\n");
    scanf("%s",plain_text);
    int num_rails,i;
    printf("ENTER NO OF RAILS\n");
    scanf("%d",&num_rails);
    int x=strlen(plain_text);
    encode(num_rails,plain_text,cipher_text);
    printf("CIPHER TEXT IS:");
    for(i=0;i<=x;i++)
    printf("%c",cipher_text[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("DECRYPTED TEXT IS:");
    decode(num_rails,cipher_text,decrypt_text,x);
    for(i=0;i<=x;i++)
    printf("%c",decrypt_text[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code for rail fence which is easier and understandable
https://cprograms4future.blogspot.in/p/list-of-all-c-programs.html?m=1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,len,rails,count,code[100][1000];
    char str[1000];
    printf("Enter a Secret Message");
    gets(str);
    len=strlen(str);
    printf("Enter number of rails\n");
    scanf("%d",&rails);
    for(i=0;i<rails;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            code[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
count=0;
j=0;
while(j<len)
{
if(count%2==0)
{
    for(i=0;i<rails;i++)
    {
        //strcpy(code[i][j],str[j]);
        code[i][j]=(int)str[j]; 
        j++;
    }

}
else
{

    for(i=rails-2;i>0;i--)
    {
        code[i][j]=(int)str[j];
    j++;
    }       
}   

count++;
}

for(i=0;i<rails;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<len;j++)
    {
        if(code[i][j]!=0)
        printf("%c",code[i][j]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, [how to crack a awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It encrypts a text to rail fence.Logic in my code is taking a string and converts them to ascii numbers.If you take the logic of rail fence the text is stored in this way if its rail is 3.00,11,22,13,04,15,26,.. Which means rows will toggle between 0-2 and 2-0 but column will always increase.After storing this thecode will be printed if the code[] is not having 0 as we have intialized it to zero before.My code will work in all conditions.Once try it and remove dislike.If you still dont understand mail me at mahidharguggilam123@gmail.com.So that i will send you with image explanation tomorrow.

Comment: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/--o1cJBQwZ3A/WHKhaF-gFqI/AAAAAAAAFaA/bf5hrVB04OEbd0fvhn5oiNTtzdvhTmimQCLcB/s1600/IMG_20170109_015001.jpg

Comment: This the explanation i made and kept in my blog. If you want visit my blog at https://cprograms4future.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_598.html?m=1 for this program

Comment: pls add all the above to your answer, not as a comment!

Answer (score -1):

It encrypts a text to rail fence.Logic in my code is taking a string and converts them to ascii numbers.If you take the logic of rail fence the text is stored in this way if its rail is 3.00,11,22,13,04,15,26,.. Which means rows will toggle between 0-2 and 2-0 but column will always increase.After storing this thecode will be printed if the code[] is not having 0 as we have intialized it to zero before.My code will work in all conditions.Once try it and remove dislike.If you still dont understand mail me at mahidharguggilam123@gmail.com.So that i will send you with image explanation tomorrow.

https://2.bp.blogspot.com/--o1cJBQwZ3A/WHKhaF-gFqI/AAAAAAAAFaA/bf5hrVB04OEbd0fvhn5oiNTtzdvhTmimQCLcB/s1600/IMG_20170109_015001.jpg

This the explanation i made and kept in my blog. If you want visit my blog visit it at https://cprograms4future.blogspot.in/p/encryption-rail-fence-cipher.html?m=1 for this program